# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.63.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to use bitcoin core in airgapped cold storage with tails installed on a usb.

first i downloaded the 0.15.1 release bin files into tails storage.
i could run the bitcoin-qt just fine.

.......................................................

now i cloned the bitcoin core from github , added a commit from github.
again i copied the 4 files - bitcoin-cli,bitcoin-qt,bitcoind,bitcoin-tx from bin folder into tails.

But now when i try to start bitcoin-qt from tails, I get the below error :

"error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.63.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

shouldnt the bitcoin-qt file from bin folder work like an executable and run independently ?

please guide how to get the bitcoin-qt within the bin folder from latest github source to work on tails usb.

Comment: i had tried to build with make . 
even after building - i got this error.